# No Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x): Vagrant stumbles even with 32-bit images

Tags: vagrant

1. CPU: Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q8200 @ 2.33GHz × 4
2. Host OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 64-bit
3. Vagrant: 1.9.7
4. Virtualbox: 5.1.24

I do:

```
$ vagrant init precise64 http://files.vagrantup.com/xenial32.box
...
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Well, I tried xenial64.box as well. And precise32.

Here is some discussion ["vagrant up" it stops at SSH auth method: private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379459/vagrant-up-it-stops-at-ssh-auth-method-private-key)

This seems to connected somehow with Intel Virtualization Technology.
Well, this CPU doesn't support it.

I will be satisfied with a 32 bit virtual machine. But how can I organize it? Well, I'd like just to start it. With or without SSH, or something. But just start.

**Could you give me a kick here?**

Comment: Connect to the display of the virtual machine to see where it is stuck.